# docker container ping other machine in host network

Tags: docker, networking, ping, host, docker-machine

I have used `avahi-daemon` package on my linux machine which is acting as a server. I have another machine(downstream device) which is able to ping the server with command `ping serverhostname.local`.
I'm running my application inside a docker container which is not able to `ping serverhostname.local`. My docker container is using the `host` network mode.